# Binding datatable to combobox of datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpfdatagrid

Hi I have to create a  wpf grid which is having combo box in it  .  I have to bind grid to a data table dtGrid and combobox item source to a datatable   dtcmb  . I wrote template below for embedding   combo box in grid  .

Now I need to access the combo in code behind to specify item source and DisplayMemberPath, ,SelectedValuePath,SelectedValue,

Even though i could access data grid in code behind I could not access combo box . what is the prob ?

```
<my:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="supplierName" Header="Supplier" Width="60" >
    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox  x:Name="cmbSubSysSupplier_SRV"  IsTextSearchEnabled="True" 
            Height="23" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Width="80" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a DataGridComboBoxColumn for this particular case. You can access it in code behind through its x:Name property. The DataGridComboBoxColumn object will give you access to all the properties you need.

Comment: how to access it from code behind.can you suggest me